# How to refactor a large xib file using Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode4, refactoring, xib

We have a large application that has 21 view controllers - all in a single xib. We'd like to refactor this into individual xib files - one per view controller. I don't see any obvious way to do this in Xcode 4. Is this possible or do I have to start from scratch?

(Answering my own question here...)

Ahah! (Eureka)

If I open a second xcode  window (File->New->Window) and create an empty .xib file, I can drag objects from the xib in the main xcode window into the empty xib in my new xcode window!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could copy and paste the views out of the big XIB and into new XIBs, but there's no automated way of doing that. By that I mean select the root view of each view controller, and paste it into the fresh XIB you'll create for each view controller.

I'm not really sure how you've managed to get 21 view controllers into a single XIB, though. There's only one "File's Owner". I suppose you could have multiple view controllers in there that end up being owned by the single file's owner, but it's a very strange way to do things. I suggest you move away ASAP (which I'm sure you're doing by asking this question!) and life will become a lot simpler.

Comment: Thanks Matt. We wound up with 21 because we didn't know what we were doing (our first project). How do I copy and paste the views? I tried right clicking on the view in the 'objects' list and even on the view window itself. I don't see any menu item, contextual or otherwise, that will let me copy a view. Thanks -

Comment: Edit -> Copy or Cmd-C. Both should be there and work - I do it all the time. Or drag them like you have found out it seems!